# Download a pdf with server node and vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I have a problem . I must create a link for download a pdf with server but when click on link the file is not downloaded .

it is important not to expose the PDF link in the client but download the file from the server.

please help me!

in front, I dit it

```
    <div class="historyNavBtns">
      <a
        v-if="isLoggedIn"
        href="/tutorial"
        @click="goLinkTutorial"
      >
        <fa-icon
          class="btn bg-blue"
          icon="info-circle"
        />
      </a>
```

my method to call api

```
  methods: {
    async goLinkTutorial () {
      try {
        await api.getLinkTutorial()
      } catch (error) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setMessage', { type: 'error', message: error, timeout: 2000 })
      }
    },
  },

}
```

in api.js

```
export async function getLinkTutorial () {
  console.log('test')
  const response = await apiClient.get('/tutorial')
  return response.data
}
```

In route

```
router.get('/', getTutorial)
```

in controller

```
import { techLogger } from '../util/logger.js'

export const getTutorial = (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.type('application/pdf').download(new URL('../upload-folder/tutorial.pdf', import.meta.url).pathname, 'tutorial.pdf')
  } catch (error) {
    techLogger.info(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the downloaded document via axios (or the apiClient) you should create a link to it and click it:

```
    <div class="historyNavBtns">
      <a
        v-if="isLoggedIn"
        href="/tutorial"
        download="tutorial.pdf"
      >
        <fa-icon
          class="btn bg-blue"
          icon="info-circle"
        />
      </a>
```

If you insist on doing this in a click handler/in javascript you could also do:

```
export async function getLinkTutorial () {
  console.log('test')
  //const response = await apiClient.get('/tutorial')
  //return response.data
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '/tutorial';
  link.setAttribute('download', 'tutorial.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is important not to expose the PDF link in the client but download the file from the server for security issues.

Comment: Well you don't. You expose /tutorial to the client one way or the other, but instead of initializing the request as an XHR request you should tell the browser to initiate a download attempt.